# ASP.NET setting a single subkey deletes the other subkeys

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, cookies

I am using subkeys of one big cookie, to store the hide state of multiple help texts.
But if a single subkey is updated, all the other subkeys are deleted.
Should I always update all the subkeys of a given cookie at the same time, to solve this?

Here's my present functions that have the problem.

```
' Store cookie_value of cookie_name  .
sub store_string( cookie_value , cookie_name  )
    ' Sets cookie cookie_name to cookie_value.
        response.Cookies( "UserSettings" )( cookie_name ) = cookie_value 
        response.Cookies( "UserSettings").Expires = datetime.now.adddays(365*10)  ' 10 years.  The hardware won't last that long!
end sub



' Retrieve stored cookie_name.
function restore_string( byval cookie_name  ) 
    ' Returns cookie named cookie_name.
        If  Request.Cookies( "UserSettings") Is Nothing Then
            return ""
        else
            cookie_value =  Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies( "UserSettings" )( cookie_name ))
            return   cookie_value
        end if
end function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some days trying to figure this out, and finally came to this solution:

If you are only editing 1 of the subkeys, you have to use the code:

```
Dim cookieCode As HttpCookie = _contxt.Request.Cookies(COOKIE_NAME)
cookieCode.Values.Set(KEY, ivalue) 
Response.Cookies.Add(cookieCode)
```

The SET command will update only the subkey. Using the full response method will overwrite the other subkeys.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue and it looks like this has been answered over on the asp.net forums here:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1819596.aspx/1

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    'add cookie
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim aCookie As New HttpCookie("userInfo")
        aCookie.Values("userName") = "UserName"
        aCookie.Values("lastVisit") = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
        Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' update subkey : "lastVisit"
    Dim cookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("userInfo")
    cookie("lastVisit") = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)

End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' show all subkey values
    Response.Write(Request.Cookies("userInfo")("userName"))
    Response.Write(Request.Cookies("userInfo")("lastVisit"))
End Sub
```